# How to view & debug pixel history of a render target in the Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio, direct3d

Using the graphics analyzer/debugger built into Visual Studio 2019, how can I view and debug the pixel history of a render target that is *not* the final frame buffer? I tried opening up the render target's Texture2D in the object table, but clicking on pixels in it does not display the pixel history like it does when I click on a pixel in the main frame buffer.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of poking around and clicking on things, I stumbled on how to do this, so I'm answering my own question. My solution is a bit inconvenient, so I'd be open to a quicker way to view the pixel history of a render target.

1. Open the captured frame in the Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer.
2. Find the render target's Texture2D in the object table and click the little counter-clockwise clock icon to view the resource history for the texture.
3. Click on one of the "Write" entries in the resource history panel. This will select the corresponding draw call in the event list, and the main view should switch over to showing the render target instead of the main frame buffer. (Note that if you had opened the actual contents of the texture in its own tab, you may not notice the main tab switch over to showing the render target.)
4. Click a pixel in the render target and you should see the pixel history for it and be able to debug the shaders.